# Is it possible to maintain scroll position after page load itself

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a "shopping cart" page where you can 'add' products to your shopping cart (which is displayed at the bottom of the page) and 'remove' them aswell. All the code is working very well, but my problem is that every time the page load, it starts at the top.

The page load itself to 'add' and 'remove' the items - so the PHP are placed right at the top of the webpage.

The page is rather long (in height), so you can understand the irritation of selecting something and then the page reloading to start at the top again.

Are there any way the the page might reload and scroll to the last known position? Or maybe have an 'onClick' function set to each product so the page can scroll down to last 'onClick' element?

I have found and tested the code below, but no luck. I am not very good with JavaScript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var xPos, yPos;
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    xPos = $get('scrollDiv').scrollLeft;
    yPos = $get('scrollDiv').scrollTop;
}
function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    $get('scrollDiv').scrollLeft = xPos;
    $get('scrollDiv').scrollTop = yPos;
}
    </script>
```

Comment: I hope, it helps .. https://mrcoles.com/blog/scroll-sneak-maintain-position-between-page-loads/

Comment: If you used AJAX for this the problem wouldn't even exist.

Comment: Not exactly the "last click position" but you could add an `id` attribute to your cart's `<div>` (`<div id="cart">` and use `#cart` in your url to jump to that div.

Comment: Look for [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to save the position.